# How can I use a custom DNS server in Azure App Services with Linux?

Tags: linux, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Core API App running in Azure App Services using Windows, but now I want to test it using Linux. The app uses a custom DNS Zone just to map a custom hostname to a specific IP address.

To implement that in my Windows App Service I used the following Application Settings as stated in [this page](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13927): `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` and `WEBSITE_ALT_DNS_SERVER`. Although it looks like a workaround, it works pretty well with Windows App Services. But in Linux it seems to have no effect and my app is not resolving the hostname as needed.

**How can I use a custom DNS server in Azure App Service with Linux or add a custom hostname like editing the hosts file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike our App Service Windows, nameresolver.exe is not available and the Application settings for "WEBSITES_ALT_DNS" and "WEBSITES_DNS" do not populate the configuration files within the container.  Below are steps are troubleshooting issues for "Alpine" based images since you don’t mention if you are using a Linux container or the default Linux OS.

Install Bind-tools-

1. apk update
2. apk add bind-tools

Run Nslookup-

Once bind-tools is installed, you'll see the server that is being used.  If bind-tools are not installed, the DNS server will not be shown.  Example provided below.

```html
9031977be93a:~# nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53
 
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.194.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4005:801::200e
```

Update Config file-

To use a different DNS server for testing, update the /etc/resolv.conf file and update the "nameserver" to use a different DNS server.  In this example, we're using Googles DNS.

1. vi /etc/resolv.conf
2. By default, the following will be in the resolv.conf file.

search reddog.microsoft.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options timeout:1 attempts:5 ndots:0cd /etc

3. If you're not familiar with "vi", press "i" on your keyboard to begin editing the file.
4. Once you're done, press "esc" and ":wq!" then enter.

search reddog.microsoft.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options timeout:1 attempts:5 ndots:0

5. Running Nslookup again, you'll see the new nameserver being used.

```html
9031977be93a:~# nslookup google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53
 
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.194.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e
```

Hardcoding Hostname-

You can also hardcode the IP address for the hostname in question for testing.  To do so, you'll need to update the following file.

1. vi /etc/hosts
2. Add the IP address that you would like the DNS to point to.  In this example, I'm changing the IP for my custom domain.

```html
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.20.0.2      9031977be93a
10.10.10.10 www.polytechniks.com
```

3. Save the changes and use "ping" or "traceroute" to see the IP being used.  NOTE: Nslookup does NOT use the /etc/hosts file so you will still see the IP address associated with the DNS.

```html
9031977be93a:~# ping www.polytechniks.com
PING www.polytechniks.com (10.10.10.10): 56 data bytes
--- www.polytechniks.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
 
9031977be93a:~# traceroute www.polytechniks.com
traceroute to www.polytechniks.com (10.10.10.10), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  172.20.0.1 (172.20.0.1)  0.005 ms  0.004 ms  0.004 ms
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan. It works pretty well. And I'm just wondering if is there any way to do it in a production environment?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you please explain by what you mean for a production environment? Do you wish to do this with Azure Web Apps for Containers (Linux)?

Comment: Well, I'm just wondering. Right now I need that but my app is still under development, so this workaround is fine, but I'm not sure if I will need that once it gets to production, so I might need a more "final" solution.